# Componente Jea Joomla

Tags: joomla

Possuo um código em PHP dentro de um componente de imobiliária que estou utilizando.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo JText::_('COM_JEA_LOCALIZATION')?></legend>
    <?php foreach ($this->form->getFieldset('localization') as $field): ?>
      <div class="formelm"><?php echo $field->label . "\n" . $field->input ?></div>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </fieldset>
```

Este Código faz com que no site a estrutura html mostre um  com várias  e dentro de cada uma um label e um input.
Saberiam apenas olhando para o código ter uma base do que se passa por trás?

Comment: Qual é exatamente a sua dúvida?

Comment: Como o código gera a estrutura em HTML citada? Tem alguns labels e inputs que gostaria de remover, porém não acho maneira.